# How to display TextBlock while a string is downloaded from server

Tags: c#, windows-phone

My app for Windows Phone has a string downloaded from server. I'm trying displaying a textBlock while the download is in execution. However, my code doesn't works.
The textBlock is not displayed. Why? Is there another way for this?

```
 WebClient webClient1 = new WebClient();
 webClient1.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadProgressCallback);
 webClient1.DownloadStringCompleted += webClient_DownloadStringCompleted1;
 webClient1.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(string.Format(url + insCodComanda.Text + "&random=" + ran.Next().ToString(), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)));

 public void DownloadProgressCallback(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
  {

     testete.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

  }

void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted1(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
      testete.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to manipulate UI element like that you need to use `Dispatcher`

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => testete.Visibility = Visibility.Visible));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This code launched an exception: `'System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher' does not contain a definition for 'Invoke' and no extension method 'Invoke' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Sorry try `this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`. I have no Windows Phone environment to test and it has some methods removed compared to WPF